# No sound with VMWare workstation when playing 3D games

Tags: vmware, audio, directx

I'm trying to set up a gaming virtual machine, because I don't want all that 'junk' on my main system.

I already have VMware Workstation 7, I decided to create a new VM with Windows 7 and Windows XP.

I've installed Unreal Tournament 2004 on both VM's. It didn't start on Windows XP, no pain, because it still runs on my Windows 7 image. When I starting this game I'm receiving the message the sound device can't be used, because the deviceID is out of range
[image: device id out of range]

> The default sound device cannot be opened:
>
> A device ID has been used
>   that is out of range for your system. Sound will be disconnected.

The Windows sounds do work, also some other games have sound (Warcraft II for example). I'm suspecting it has something to do with DirectX or Direct3D sounds. If I remember correctly, Half-Life (CS1.6) also don't have sound enabled, because of the same error. Counterstrike Source has sound in the menu, but after starting up a game it's gone with the same error.

Any advice or suggestions?

I have already found some sites telling me I should [change the sound device to a Soundblaster](http://www.scampers.org/steve/vmware/#sound), but that only applied for old DOS games.

**Edit**

I'm playing Doom 3 on the VM now and it does have sound.
I'm pretty sure it has DirectX support. Then again, it appears it doesn't use DirectSound.

Warcraft 2, Warcraft 3, Unreal Tournament (classic), Quake 3 also got sound when playing.

I'm trying out UT2003 today and it also has sound enabled, I can hear everything. On Software 3D, Hardware 3D and safe mode.

By request, my VMX files.
First my Windows 7 machine:

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "7"
numvcpus = "4"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "2"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsisas1068"
memsize = "2048"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "Game 7.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.autodetect = "FALSE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.startConnected = "FALSE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
roamingVM.exitBehavior = "go"
displayName = "Game 7"
guestOS = "windows7-64"
nvram = "Game 7.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
extendedConfigFile = "Game 7.vmxf"
ide1:0.fileName = "D:"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
ide1:0.startConnected = "TRUE"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:e8:85:9e"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
uuid.location = "56 4d 8f 49 68 58 4f 4e-0e f0 f5 31 4e e8 85 9e"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 8f 49 68 58 4f 4e-0e f0 f5 31 4e e8 85 9e"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
unity.wasCapable = "TRUE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
scsi0.sasWWID = "50 05 05 69 68 58 4f 40"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "134217728"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "1323861406"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:0.deviceType = "mouse"
hgfs.mapRootShare = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "F:\Temp\VMShare"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "VMShare"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
```

My Windows XP machine looks like this:

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "7"
memsize = "2048"
ide0:0.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.fileName = "UML.vhd"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.fileName = ""
floppy0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
roamingVM.exitBehavior = "go"
displayName = "UML Machine"
guestOS = "winxppro"
nvram = "UML Machine.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
printers.enabled = "TRUE"
extendedConfigFile = "UML Machine.vmxf"
sound.virtualDev = "es1371"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:10:10:79"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
uuid.location = "56 4d 32 87 54 f5 1b df-46 45 83 91 b9 10 10 79"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 32 87 54 f5 1b df-46 45 83 91 b9 10 10 79"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "-1"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "134217728"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "-1190129543"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:0.deviceType = "mouse"
ide0:0.redo = ""
ide1:0.startConnected = "TRUE"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
unity.wasCapable = "FALSE"
ide1:0.fileName = "auto detect"
debugStub.winOffsets.version = "7"
debugStub.winOffsets.value = "0x88,0x84,0x18,0x190,0x174,16,416,0x22c,0x228,0x1f0,0x224,0x20,0x18,0x18,0x20,0x24,4,0x11c,0x8,0x0,0x14,0x100000,0x1b0,0xc,0xc,0x18,0x13c,0x1f4"
```

Comment: do you have a sound device installed? can you post your .vmx file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to fine tune ***numvcpus*** based on ***cpuid.coresPerSocket*** value in your vmx.

Some VMWare users found out that ["vmware can only work right with the original cores."](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/328576)

You could give a try by setting

```
numvcpus
```

to the ***same*** value than

```
cpuid.coresPerSocket
```

in your vmx file, i.e.

```
numvcpus = "2"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "2"
```

Keep in mind that in any case, one has to

```
"Ensure that the number of vCPUs is divisible by the number of cpuid.coresPerSocket
in the virtual machine. That is, when you divide the number of vCPUs by the number
of cpuid.coresPerSocket , it must return an integer value. For example, if your
virtual machine is created with 8 vCPUs, coresPerSocket can only be 1, 2, 4, or 8."
```

([source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010184))

Comment: Setting numvcpus value to the same value than cpuid.coresPerSocket, allowed my to fix the 'Audio stuttering on VMware Workstation with multiple cores/cpus' bug. see http://communities.vmware.com/thread/328576